# Limit the values in autosuggest textbox

Tags: php, javascript, autosuggest

I having a autosuggest textbox with some values.

while typing a first letter into the text box it shows all the related values of the text in dropdown.

I want to limit the displaying related values to 20?..

my code look like this,

```
    $("#input_id").autoSuggest(data.items, { 
                     selectedItemProp: "tag", 
                     searchObjProps: "tag", 
                     selectedValuesProp: "id", 
                     startText: "", 
                     keyDelay: 50,
                     minChars: 1,
                     asHtmlID: "input_id",
                     preFill: [ ] 
    });
```

Comment: Return only 20 results from your php code which works on the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code `retrieveLimit:20`, Documentation [**Here**](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

```
$("#input_id").autoSuggest(data.items, { 
                     selectedItemProp: "tag", 
                     searchObjProps: "tag", 
                     selectedValuesProp: "id", 
                     startText: "", 
                     keyDelay: 50,
                     minChars: 1,
                     asHtmlID: "input_id",
                     preFill: [ ],
                     retrieveLimit:20
    });
```

Comment: Not optimal as the server will still send the full list.

Comment: @Pushpesh- yeah but i suggested as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Rerturn only matched 20 values from your PHP page

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT to restrict the maximum number of results in the PHP code.

Example:

```
    $sql = "select  field from column where column LIKE '%$input_id%' LIMIT 20";
```

Now when we print the contents. There will be maximum of 20 results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quicklook at the autoSuggest documentation and didn't really find anything to limit the results, but i would limit it in the Query, assuming you are retrieving it via Ajax from a script.

You could just limit your SQL by doing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... LIMIT 20`

Or modify the script just to return 20 values